# Performance: order of tables in joined statement

Tags: performance, join, sqlite

I have the following SQL statement, running on a SQLite database on a Windows mobile device.

```
SELECT 
    table1.uniqueidentifier1, table1.int1, table1.varchar1, 
    table1.decimal1, table1.decimal2 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 On table1.PK = table2.FK
WHERE table2.uniqueidentifier2 IN (uniqueidentifier1,uniqueidentifier2,....)
ORDER BY table1.varchar1
```

As there are several hundred thousand records in each table and the device isn't really new this takes some time.

Would the performance be better, if I switched the tables, somehow like this:

```
SELECT 
    table1.uniqueidentifier1, table1.int1, table1.varchar1, 
    table1.decimal1, table1.decimal2 
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 On table1.PK = table2.FK
WHERE table2.uniqueidentifier2 IN (uniqueidentifier1,uniqueidentifier2,....)
ORDER BY table1.varchar1
```

Please note: in the first statement I select from table **1**` and join table **2**, in the second, it is switched.

Why or why not is it faster?

Comment: Have you tried running the two queries and compared the result?
Generally speaking there shouldn't be much - if any - performance differences because the database engine should be able to calculate the proper plan for both.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite automatically chooses the estimated optimal join order; the table order in the query has no effect.

There are two ways to optimize this query.
If the filter on `uniqueidentifier2` removes most `table1` records from the result, then it would be fastest to look up `table2` records with matching `uniqueidentifier2` values first, then to look up the corresponding `table1` records, and then to sort the result.
This would require the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX t2_uid2_idx ON table2(uniqueidentifier2);
-- CREATE INDEX t1_pk ON table1(PK);  -- primary keys have this automatically
```

If most `table1` records will show up in the result, then it would be more efficient to go through `table1` in the proper order and look up correspondig `table2` records.
This would require the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX t1_vc1_idx ON table1(varchar1);
CREATE INDEX t2_FK_uid2_idx ON table2(FK, uniqueidentifier2);
```

(Having `uniqueidentifier2` in the second index optimizes for this particular query, but might be not worth the storage and update overhead if you have many other queries.)

---

To check how queries are actually implemented, execute [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).